# Set implicit style in code behind

Tags: silverlight, resources, styles

We've an application in which we have the default control styles defined as implicit style.

XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    [...]
</Style>
```

These styles are now applied to every button in the application.

Sometimes we change the style in code-behind to something different.

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="HighlightStyle" TargetType="Button">
    [...]
</Style>
```

Code:

```
cmdButton.Style = App.Current.Resources("HighlightStyle")
```

Then again we want to remove the style and return to the implicit style, but this doesn't seem to be possible:

Code:

```
cmdButton.Style = Nothing
```

Results in an unstyled `Button`.

I've also read here http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx that all implicit style should be accessible by the TargetType-Value as Key, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, as soon as i've posted the question, i've come up with a solution:

Using the ClearValue Method on the Object clears the style property leaving it on the default style.

```
cmdButton.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.StyleProperty)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about - to add `Key` for default `Style` and instead of `cmdButton.Style = Nothing;` do `cmdButton.Style = App.Current.Resources("DefaultButtonStyle");`.

If you does not like this solution you can read a couple articles about `VisualStateManager`. But for implementing it you should rewrite a bit your logic.

Comment: Yes this would be possible of course, but it would mean that the style would not longer be implicit and therefore not automatically set to all Buttons in the application.